# Xamarin Forms - Delete Row from ListView and Observable Collection

Tags: c#, ios, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a simple question. How do you delete a row from ListView that is binded to an observable collection?

Here's my XAML code:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding products}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                            <MenuItem ClassId="{Binding ProductName}" Clicked="DeleteAction" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="true" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding ProductImage}" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding ProductPrice, StringFormat='{0:C}'}" />

                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

CS code

```
public ViewShoppingCart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyListView.ItemsSource = ShoppingCart.fbproducts;
        }


private void DeleteAction(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
// something goes here
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ShoppingCart.fbproducts` will hold the same instance of the `ObservableCollection` and not recreating it. all you need to do is

```
ShoppingCart.fbproducts.Remove(ItemYouWantToRemove)
```

Comment: Thanks @TheGeneral! It's working! Flawless Victory.